# Finding a formula for a bounded function on the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, products, maximum-principle

[image]

This is an exercise from Conway. I managed to solve (a), but am stuck at (b). How can I find a formula for the function f with just the value at z=0? I have suspicions that f must be some finite blaschke product, but can't prove it... Could anyone please help me?

Comment: The first part put the conditions to apply [Schwarz's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma) to $f(z) \frac{1}{M} \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1-\overline{z_k}z}{z-z_k}$

Comment: Schwarz lemma needs the value of the function at z=0 to be 0. But the function you suggested is not 0 at z=0.

Comment: I think @reuns meant the maximum principle, not the Schwarz lemma.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Apply the maximum principle to 
$$g(z) = f(z) \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1-\overline{z_k}z}{z-z_k}$$
observing that as $z$ approaches the boundary of $D$, 
$$|g(z)| \le M \prod_{k=1}^n \left|\frac{1-\overline{z_k}z}{z-z_k}\right| \to M$$
Hence $|g|\le M$ in $D$.

(b) If $f(0)=Me^{i\alpha}z_1\cdots z_n$, then $g(0)=(-1)^nMe^{i\alpha}$. The maximum principle says that only constant functions can attain the maximum of their modulus inside of the domain. Hence $g\equiv (-1)^nMe^{i\alpha}$, which yields a formula for $f$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think there is a typo in the exercise. Have you set α as a real number?

Comment: Yes, $\alpha$ is real. The way the exercise puts $z$ in there is weird, possibly a typo.

Comment: I think it is z_k - z instead of z - z_k in g(z) of your answer.

Comment: Could be that, but I didn't want to change the standard form of Mobius transformations, so threw in $(-1)^n$ in $g(0)$.